# Handling chunks of Data from Node/Express Backend using React/Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I created an Express Backend which sends JSON data as a chunk of text using res.write(JSON.stringify(JSONChunk)).

I want to handle and process each chunck of res.write in react front end and am using the following method:

My Backend pseudo code

```
for(let i = 0; i < slices; i ++) {
      var JSONChunck = await getData(i); // getData operation can take some time
      res.write(JSON.stringify(JSONChunck)); 
}
res.end();
```

FE pseudocode:

```
fetch(API, OPTS).then(async (response) => {
     const reader = response.body.getReader();
     while (true) {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read();
          if (done) {
                break;
          }
          var text = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
          var result = JSON.parse(text);
          var processedResult = process(result);
     }          
})
```

However, when I try the above code in some systems, I receive an error when trying to do JSON.parse(text) and see that the value of 'text' does not fetch full JSON string and only a partial string.

I was wondering if I am doing anything wrong or if there is any better way to do the above.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: JSON is text, and sending that in chunks requires waiting for the entire text to be received before you can parse it back into an object. Similarly, your backend code suggests that `JSONChunk` is not a chunk or JSON but an object, since you're calling `JSON.stringify()` on it without error(?) (I also don't understand why you're doing all this manually; why not simply load the entire JSON string? why chunks?)

Comment: I am logging my JSON.stringify statements and it seems to be valid and I don't get any error on JSON.stringify. I observed that when the error occurs in react, some part of the slice is in the next reader.read() / text. I am not sure why!

Comment: Can you show more of the relevant backend code? How are you creating `JSONChunk`? This all seems weird; why not simply use `.then(r => r.json()).then(obj => ...)` after your fetch() call, as usual?

Comment: Also about getting full JSON string, it is a limitation in my BE as it takes some to generate each JSON chunk. It can take upto 30 mins to generate full JSON and hence I want to provide some data in my FE.

Comment: Ok sure, so break apart your object into smaller objects and send those. However I don't see how that requires what you're doing, even if it worked that way, which it won't. Just use `res.json(smaller_obj);` in your backend, and receive it like I stated. Unless I'm missing something big here, you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. If the big thing I'm missing isn't in your question, you need to add it, because this is almost certainly an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and we're already wasting time

Comment: Added small BE pseudocode.I'm sorry, I am a little new to react/JS and have a different background. But if I am not wrong I can't send chunks of data using res.json() as it inherently calls res.end()?

Comment: Are you sure that each res.write() will correspond to exactly one reader.read()? I don't think that's going to happen. Anyway, I'd run multiple fetch calls instead, with each getting a single slice of data. What exactly does `getData` do? Why does it take up to 30 minutes? Maybe creating a socket connection instead would be a better solution.